# Scanf return value ignored and function refinition; different basic type

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and am trying to do a booking system for my assignment. I've been faced with this error multiple time with no idea how to solve it.

I've tried what Visual Studio recommend which is to change the scanf to scanf_s. However, this does not work either. As for the function unidentified error I have no idea on where to fix it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char MainMenu()
{
   int sel;
   sel = 1, 2, 3, 4;
   printf("WELCOME TO WISDOM COLLEGE HOTEL\n\n");
   printf("Please choose your desired service:\n");
   printf("1.Booking\n");
   printf("2.Check Room Availability\n");
   printf("3.Payment detail\n");
   printf("4.Exit\n");
   if (scanf_s("%d",&sel) == 1) {
       return Booking();
   }
   else if (scanf_s("%d", &sel) == 2) {
       return Room();
   }
   else if (scanf_s("%d", &sel) == 3) {
       return Payment();
   }
}

char Booking()
{
   int selBook;
   printf("\t\t\t\t BOOKING\n\n");
   printf("Book base on:\n");
   printf("1.Gender\n");
   printf("2.Room Type\n");
   printf("3.Back to Main Menu\n");
   scanf_s("%d", &selBook);
   printf("\n%d", selBook);
}

char Room()
{
   int selRoom;
   printf("\t\t\t ROOM AVAILABILITY\n\n");
   printf("Check room availability by:\n");
   printf("1.Type\n");
   printf("2.Gender\n");
   if (scanf_s("%d", &selRoom) == 1) {
       return 0;
   }
}

char main()
{
   char MainMenu;
   char Booking;
   char Payment;
   char Room;
   return MainMenu;
}
```

I expect the program to run so the MainMenu run first, and based on user input, it will then go from Booking to Exit.

Comment: I would recommend reading the manual page for `scanf_s`

Comment: Also `char main()` is incorrect.

Comment: "I've tried what Visual Studio recommend which is to change the scanf to scanf_s." T_T

Comment: If you are new to C, you should not use either scanf or scanf_s or any variant of scanf.  Read input with fgets, fread, or fgetc and parse the data yourself.  You will learn far more doing this than you will learning the quirks of the scanf format language.

Answer (score 0):

you should first get the input and then check what it is.

[scanf_s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019) doesnt return the value which you entered as input, it's return value is the number of fields which successfully converted and assigned.
So you should first get the input and save it in the memory and then check what it's value.

Also, I didnt know what you tried to do with MainMenu that was the return value of char main() (i dont think its common to use char main - use *int* or *void* main istead):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char MainMenu();
char Booking();
char Payment();
char Room();

char MainMenu()
{
   int sel;
   sel = 1, 2, 3, 4;
   printf("WELCOME TO WISDOM COLLEGE HOTEL\n\n");
   printf("Please choose your desired service:\n");
   printf("1.Booking\n");
   printf("2.Check Room Availability\n");
   printf("3.Payment detail\n");
   printf("4.Exit\n");
   scanf_s("%d",&sel)
   if (sel == 1) {
       return Booking();
   }
   else if (sel == 2) {
       return Room();
   }
   else if (sel == 3) {
       return Payment();
   }
}

char Booking()
{
   int selBook;
   printf("\t\t\t\t BOOKING\n\n");
   printf("Book base on:\n");
   printf("1.Gender\n");
   printf("2.Room Type\n");
   printf("3.Back to Main Menu\n");
   scanf_s("%d", &selBook);
   printf("\n%d", selBook);
}

char Room()
{
   int selRoom;
   printf("\t\t\t ROOM AVAILABILITY\n\n");
   printf("Check room availability by:\n");
   printf("1.Type\n");
   printf("2.Gender\n");
   if (scanf_s("%d", &selRoom) == 1) {
       return 0;
   }
}

int main()
{
   MainMenu();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wny `char MainMenu;`  - it is not used in the scope

Comment: @EdHeal I didnt know what the post owner tried to do. also room and payment arent in use and both of them are functions names. I think he tought its mendatory to declare them in main.

Comment: I have fixed the forward declarations. But the function `Room` does not always specify the return value. Ditto for the others